# PHP - Unix timestamp

Tags: php, sql, database

I have this:

```
$time = time();
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lastlogin>'$time-86000'
```

How do I select from the database, where the lastlogin has been completed within the last 24 hours?

I also have this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE signupdate>'$time-86000'
```

What I wish to archive here is, how do I select from the database, where the last signupdate is within 24 hours

Comment: Does the code above work or not? What does your full code look like? What type is the `lastlogin` column?

Comment: What sort of database you are using? And the table schema for this table?

Comment: What's surprising is using timestamp instead of `date` type that allows easy date manipulation..

Comment: Side note: 24 hours is `60*60*24 = 86,400`, not `86,000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql can handle unix timestamps as well

```
select * from table where stamp > unix_timestamp() - 24*3600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(signupdate,.'date('h-i-s).') FROM users;
```

Then if it is above 1 its more than 24hours, else its not.

Ill try to see if i can get into a where clause...